# What is the purpose of Semaphore.wait(timeout: .now())?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

Looking at some Apple code sample, I found this:

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    // wait() is used to drop new notifications if old ones are still processing, to avoid queueing up a bunch of stale data.
    if metadataObjectsOverlayLayersDrawingSemaphore.wait(timeout: .now()) == .success {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Some processing...

            self.metadataObjectsOverlayLayersDrawingSemaphore.signal()
        }
    }
}
```

***Context of the code***: This is the delegate method when using video capture to detect a QR code (or any other code).
Because it is triggered many times per second (if the camera stays on the same QR code), some kind of timeout is needed.

But how does `DispatchSemaphore.wait(timeout: .now())` work? And why check if it is `.success`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The purpose is what the comment says:

> wait() is used to drop new notifications if old ones are still processing, to avoid queueing up a bunch of stale data.

and it works as follows:

- The semaphore is created with a value of one.
- When `metadataOutput` is called the first time, `wait(timeout: .now())`
  succeeds and decrements the value of the semaphore to zero. 
  The processing of the data begins.
- If `metadataOutput` is called again *before* the processing has
  completed, the semaphore still has a value of zero. 
  Then `wait(timeout:)` would wait for the semaphore to become
  positive again, but since the timeout value is `now()`, it fails
  immediately and returns `.timedOut`.
  The effect is that the incoming data is ignored, the `metadataOutput`
  callback method returns immediately.
- When the data processing on the has completed,
  the semaphore is signaled, which increases the value to one.
  As a consequence, the *next* time the callback is called, 
  waiting for the semaphore will succeed and the data is processed again.

So in short:

- `wait(timeout: .now())` returns `.success` if a 
  previously submitted block has signaled completion, in that case
  a new block is submitted for processing the incoming data.
- `wait(timeout: .now())` returns `.timedOut` if a previously
  submitted block is still running, in that case the incoming data
  is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it normal that when I put a break point in the `// Some processing...` part at the very first call of `metadataOutput` it stops then when I release the breakpoint, I get all of sudden many calls triggered as if they actually stacked?

Comment: @Kalzem: I don't know.

Comment: Okay, will try to figure it out ;) Thanks!